# Cast string value to type Of T

Tags: vb.net

I have such kind of function:

```
Public Shared Function ResolveService(Of T As Class)() As T
            Return Container.Resolve(Of T)
End Function
```

Normall way of passing object there is like:

```
Dim protocol = FactoryConnections.ResolveService(of Iftp)  /or Isftp...
```

However my value as string for instance Iftp is in string. How to case it in the place `(Of ...)` ?

Tried so far using GetType/typeOf however no one seems to work:

```
Dim stringvalue as Type = Type.GetType("Iftp")
Dim protocol = FactoryConnections.ResolveService(Of stringvalue)
```

**Note** that i am calling that outside Factory class where that function comming from...
It seems i cannot pass to place `(Of <here>)`

Comment: Anime to answer please

Comment: You can't do this using the generic method.  You'll need a method that takes a string argument (or a `Type` argument) and returns an `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, but to get the name of the Generic T you can use

> dim stringvalue = GetType(T).Name

or

> dim stringvalue = GetType(T).FullName

if you want the namespace too.

Comment: Anime to answer please